# Bootstrap 3 100% Height DIV with Navbar and Sticky Footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a layout using a fixed navbar and sticky footer. In the main body, I have a fluid container with a column aligned to the left. I want that column to vertically fill the main body (between the navbar and footer), however I can't get it to work. I've tried all the examples I can find, to no avail.

I've build this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gtowle/uger2o69/) to show what I have so far.

This is what I'm hoping to achieve:

[image]

My HTML:

```
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 ">
      <div class="main-content">
        <h1>Hello world.</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        Sticky footer based on <a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/">Boostrap example</a>.
    </div>
</footer>
```

And my CSS:

```
/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #999999;
}

/* Custom page CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */
/* Not required for template or sticky footer method. */
body > .container-fluid {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.container-fluid .col-sm-6 {
  padding: 0;
}
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.footer {
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.main-content {
  background: #efefef;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `height:calc(100vh - 110px);` on the `.main-content` div. The 110px is the height of the footer + height of the header which is subtracted from the viewport height.

http://www.bootply.com/v8XITHB4fP